# Windows Store 8.1 AES Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-runtime

I am new for encryption I have tried with many things but my requirement is like

```js
key1 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('abc');
ivKey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('xyz');
pwdval = 'username';

function encyptionFun(pwdval) {
    var encyptedval = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pwdval), key1,
        {
            keySize: 128 / 8,
            iv: ivKey,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
    encyptedval = encodeURIComponent(encyptedval);
    return encyptedval;
}
```

this is JavaScript code now I have to convert into native how I would do In C# AES algo.

I have my code like :

Adding on more algorith for it.

```
 public static string Encrypt(string dataToEncrypt, string password, string salt)
    {
        // Generate a key and IV from the password and salt
        IBuffer aesKeyMaterial;
        IBuffer iv;
        uint iterationCount = 10000;
        GenerateKeyMaterial(password, salt, iterationCount, out aesKeyMaterial, out iv);

        IBuffer plainText = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(dataToEncrypt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        // Setup an AES key, using AES in CBC mode and applying PKCS#7 padding on the input
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider aesProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
        CryptographicKey aesKey = aesProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(aesKeyMaterial);

        // Encrypt the data and convert it to a Base64 string
        IBuffer encrypted = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(aesKey, plainText, iv);
        return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(encrypted);
    }

    private static void GenerateKeyMaterial(string password, string salt, uint iterationCount, out IBuffer keyMaterial, out IBuffer iv)
    {
        // Setup KDF parameters for the desired salt and iteration count
        IBuffer saltBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(salt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        KeyDerivationParameters kdfParameters = KeyDerivationParameters.BuildForPbkdf2(saltBuffer, iterationCount);

        // Get a KDF provider for PBKDF2, and store the source password in a Cryptographic Key
        KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider kdf = KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(KeyDerivationAlgorithmNames.Pbkdf2Sha256);
        IBuffer passwordBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(password, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        CryptographicKey passwordSourceKey = kdf.CreateKey(passwordBuffer);

        // Generate key material from the source password, salt, and iteration count.  Only call DeriveKeyMaterial once,
        // since calling it twice will generate the same data for the key and IV.
        int keySize = 128 / 8;
        int ivSize = 128 / 8;
        uint totalDataNeeded = (uint)(keySize + ivSize);
        IBuffer keyAndIv = CryptographicEngine.DeriveKeyMaterial(passwordSourceKey, kdfParameters, totalDataNeeded);

        // Split the derived bytes into a seperate key and IV
        byte[] keyMaterialBytes = keyAndIv.ToArray();
        keyMaterial = WindowsRuntimeBuffer.Create(keyMaterialBytes, 0, keySize, keySize);
        iv = WindowsRuntimeBuffer.Create(keyMaterialBytes, keySize, ivSize, ivSize);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code uses CBC mode whereas your C# code uses ECB mode (both options). They have to be the same: preferably CBC mode with a random IV.

Also your C# code hashes a password to get the key. That doesn't happen in JavaScript (maybe you just forgot to show it).

Comment: Hi Artjom, I javaScript  "iv: ivKey", this is string key how I would achiev in int keySize = 128 / 8;
        int ivSize = 128 / 8;
        uint totalDataNeeded = (uint)(keySize + ivSize);
this format.

Comment: Instead of adding more code that you found on the internet, you should show your complete CryptoJS code. I don't know what ivKey is supposed to be. The supposed key is also named pwdval which is also wrong since keys are not passwords.

Comment: So, you converted the CryptoJS code to Android and iOS before? This is a bad idea. The "key" and "iv" are incomplete in the CryptoJS code. CryptoJS doesn't throw an error, but silently pads the key and iv to a valid number of bytes (16 bytes) using 0x00 bytes. If you *really* want to do the same thing in C#, then you should remove the key derivation and instead simply pad the given key and iv. Note that you really should port what you currently have in C# to CryptoJS.

Comment: right but it already working on android and iOS so client will not allow to change anything what ever need I have to sync accordingly.even android and iOS newly plugin so no earlier any data.